# How to change the range of point sizes when point size represents values

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I would like to retain the relative size differential between points in a ggplot2 scatter plot, but increase the size of all of the points so they're more visible.

Here's the code.  The only relevant point is that point size is tied to a variable so i don't want to adjust it manually.

```
ggplot(WSC5, aes(x = DCount, y = meandays, color = Department, size = NumCats)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "Mean Number of Days Open Per Case", 
       x = "Number of Cases", 
       title = "Cases", 
       size = "Number of Categories") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5)) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size =5)))
```

The above code produces a workable chart but the points are too small to be visible in a slide presentation.  I want bigger points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I think you can get what you need with `scale_size()`

```r
df <-
  diamonds %>% 
  filter(clarity == "I1") %>%
  mutate(
    depth = floor(depth),
    price = round(price, -3)
  ) %>% 
  count(depth, price)

no_scale <-
  ggplot(df, aes(depth, price, size = n)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1/1000)

with_scale <-
  ggplot(df, aes(depth, price, size = n)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_size(
    breaks = c(1, 10, 25, 50),
    range = c(2, 6)
  ) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1/1000)             

gridExtra::grid.arrange(no_scale, with_scale, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

To get good results on this site, always give some code that will create a small dataset so we can run it on our own. This article has good info on how to do this:

https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html

Comment: Thank you.  It stretched my very limited technical abilities to the limit to get the original post placed, but conceptually I see the benefit of the reprex idea.   I'll try the code you provided.   Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Update: Victory!

Comment: +
  scale_size(range = c(0,25))  did the trick all by itself.